# How to handle empty listView on fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment

How to show empty view, maybe with text saying no data.. if the String array is null

```
public class SermonsFragment extends ListFragment {
    private String[] sermonsList = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //ListView for the sermon list
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
             (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sermonsList);
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);

        //Some people use this but I can't use this syntax somehow
        //SetEmptyView();


    }
```

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#222222" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Shows an image from your drawable resources -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/series_banner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/series_banner" />
        <!-- Closing tag for the horizontal nested layout -->

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No Data" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I see some people use setEmptyView, but it does not work for me, I believe due to using ListAdapter.

Which bring me to another mini question, what's the different between ListView and ListAdapter, ArrayAdapter?. When to use which one.

Comment: Use this lib https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Empty-Layout
for set empty view and loading view in listview

Comment: Hey, you should look for [SetEmptyView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29)

Comment: @krisnik look at my description. I took a look at setEmptyView but does not work for me, e.g: it's not a valid syntax most likely due to using listadapter. but correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case actually because of I did not check

```
if(listAdapter.getCount() == 0)
```

which cause `setListAdapter(listAdapter)` error.

I dont have to do anything else, after that it will automaticly show

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Data" />
```

without needed to do anything else.

Answer (score 2):

If you can not use from `setEmptyView` ,Create a layout which contain your empty message. for example:

```
<TextView
    android:text="No results found"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/EmptytextView"
    android:visibility="Gone"/>
```

then check your adapter count:

```
if(listadapter.getCount() == 0)
    emptytextview.setVisibility(View.Visible);
```

Comment: do you mean to create a new layout .xml file or just put a textview in the fragment layout?

Comment: @Harts No difference. Best way is put it in layout which have your listview. Good luck

Comment: I can't use setvisibility, the option does not come out. please check my xml file in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your xml file is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<view
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/empty_state_favorites_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star_black_124dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_for_empty_view_favorites"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/empty_view_text_color" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/text_for_empty_view_favorites"
        android:textColor="@color/empty_view_text_color" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in the fragment class you have to set some condition. like

```
    if (adapter.getItemCount()==0){
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

if your adapter data is zero then it will show empty state and if your adapter has some data it will show those data's.